# Brand new to gwt

Tags: web-applications, gwt, jakarta-ee

1. Can you go from module to module with gwt. For instance when you click to submit login information can you get rid of that ui and go to a new ui for whatever your app happens to do?
2. Also are there any books or tutorials anyone recommends? I have a good understanding of how the ui structures work, but am confused when it comes to things like the *.gwt.xml file and the web.xml. I want to learn as quickly as possible so any advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regarding (1): Yes it is entirely possible.

Comment: Thank you for answer, but I was looking for some insight on how to do this. Most tutorials show a one ui example with no transfer. Can a second class extend EntryPoint somehow? or is there some other way to do it. With j2se it is easy to dispose and add to layouts, but since I am new to gwt I am not quite sure how to go about this.

Comment: It's been a while since I have done this but I believe I was swapping `panel` class instances to achieve this. Basically, in your `root` panel, you can decide to switch from a S1 (subclass of panel class) to S2 "on-the-fly".

Comment: ahhh thank you very much I will have to give that a shot, another option I was thinking about is if I could clear() the rootpanel like i can clear a regular panel and then I could load up another ui. Problem is clear() is a non static method.

Comment: God...haha it would be RootPanel.get().clear() that was dumb of me, sometimes I panic when I am learning something so foreign to me instead of just thinking. So that may also solve the problem.

Comment: @John: then my answer+comment are satisfactory?

Comment: Yeah I believe that is how you would do it. It just stinks that there is not a simpler way to move from one .html to another. Can you also recommend any reading online, or in texts on the subject? I went through a few tutorials and they were all great but everything just wants you to use the eclipse plugin and that auto creates the gwt.xml file along with the web.xml file. This typically wouldnt be a problem but I want to eventually use gwtext and I know I will have to edit these files which i have no idea about. Just if you could point me in the right direction I would appreciate it alot.

Comment: I can't recommend GwtDesigner (from Instantiations) enough: it is a great tool!  All the GUI layout is done for you. This should serve as good tutorial: just look at the generated code!

Comment: @John: just FYI: have you read the FAQ of this site? I see you are new here.  When a answer satisfies you, it is a good practice to accept it ( the check box ). Cheers.

Comment: will that help me understand the xml files? it seems like that piece is just expected to be understood

Comment: @John: I had to sweat on this too... like everybody else I believe. I haven't done GWT in some months now: why don't you search on GoogleCode for a GWT project and look at the source code?

Answer (score 0):

What I have is a rather complex tutorial combination of gae gdata and gwt:

http://h2g2java.blessedgeek.com/2009/08/tablemgr-gae-gwt-gdata-with-rpc.html.

I am currently working on a project using Vaadin. Download vaadin and look at the sampler and demo codes.

Vaadin makes some changes to the way you work/develop with gwt.